Unable to remove a HashMap entry by key object even when the key is confirmed to exist using Java HashMap in Kotlin
I need help understanding why I can't remove an entry from a hashmap by an data class object key.
The expectation is that the incoming entry is a key that exists in the map. All markups are immutable data class objects. Sometimes this is failing so in order to understand and trap this cause, I put a series of runtime asserts to check the problem.
val markupFeatureCollection = HashMap<Markup, Feature>()

fun remove(entry: Markup) {
    // the entry is guaranteed to be a valid key for an entry
    val feature = markupFeatureCollection.remove(entry)

    // oh no, this shouldn't happen. We want to re-associate a markup with it's feature. In this special case
    // the markup changed visibility but the feature representation of it should be preserved so it can be
    // shown again without having to rebuild it.
    if (feature == null) {
        // actually look for the markup key in the collection by id
        val member = markupFeatureCollection.filter { it.key.uuid == entry.uuid }

        // assert that there's a feature for this markup
        member.values.first()

        // get the key
        val markup = member.keys.first()

        // sanity test, does the markup we've failed to look up match the one we found with the same id
        assert(markup == entry) {
            "entry key was found ing markupFeatureCollection but could not be removed"
        }

        assert(markup === entry) {
            "entry key was found ing markupFeatureCollection but could not be removed"
        }

        // sanity test, log both side-by-side to compare the values
        println("xxx: $markup")
        println("xxx: $entry")

        // making it this far, markup is a key that came from this collection. The following line must
        // be true
        // ALWAYS FAILS
        assert(markupFeatureCollection.containsKey(markup))
    }
}

In the code above, feature is guaranteed to be non-null for incoming entry. For some reason if this fails I'm looking up the entry by its id. Even though I've retreived the key directly from the map, the runtime asserts pass,
assert(markupFeatureCollection.containsKey(markup))
still always fails.
Why is this happening. Same behavior using mutableScatterMapOf()
Edit - I can't provide the entire source but this should help.
abstract class Markup(
    open val uuid: String,
    open val name: String,
    open val geoJson: JsonObject
)

data class Waypoint(
    override val uuid: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    override val name: String = createDefaultName(),
    override val geoJson: JsonObject
):Markup(
    uuid = uuid,
    name = name,
    geoJson = geoJson,
)

The hash key (the subject of this post) is a Waypoint. Neither Waypoint nor Markup provide overrides for hashCode() or equals().
All of the members of each are declared as val.
Update - I was naive in my assumption about how a hashmap captuers an object key hash. I don't want to override the equals and hashing functions, so I was able to compromise some perf and use the markup uuids instead. Here's the unit test for exploring the behavior.
    @Test
    fun `hashmap computed key test`(){
        data class Waypoint(
            val uuid: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
            val geoJson: JsonObject = JsonObject()
        )

        val waypoint = Waypoint()

        val hashMap = HashMap<Waypoint, String>()
        hashMap[waypoint] = "waypointFeature"

        assertTrue(hashMap.containsKey(waypoint))
        assertTrue(hashMap[waypoint] == "waypointFeature")

        waypoint.geoJson.addProperty("locationName", "Home")

        // because geoJson's hash identity has changed, waypoint is no longer a valid key into the hash,
        // and the hash entry is now unreachable even when try to use the the actual hash entry as a key.
        assertFalse(hashMap.containsKey(waypoint))
        assertFalse(hashMap[waypoint] == "waypointFeature")

        val entry = hashMap.filter { it.key.uuid == waypoint.uuid }.keys.first()

        assertTrue(waypoint == entry)
        assertFalse(hashMap.containsKey(entry))
        assertTrue(hashMap[waypoint] == null)

        entry.geoJson.remove("locationName")

        // restored the ability to reach our entry by key
        assertTrue(hashMap.containsKey(entry))
        assertTrue(hashMap[waypoint] == "waypointFeature")
    }


Where do the Feature values come from that you are putting into the HashMap? If they come from Java, then implicitly their type is Feature!. In that case, for val feature = markupFeatureCollection.remove(entry), feature would be null if the HashMap mapped entry to null. Have you tried dumping markupFeatureCollection to Logcat to see what is in there?

Thanks commonsware - features are also asserted to be non-null before the markup, feature pair is added.

Also, the if block is asserting that the markup key I'm looking for is still in the map since we get all the way to the last assert and it always fails
assert(markupFeatureCollection.containsKey(markup))

I think the question might be, if I get a key directly from the hashmap and then on the next line ask if the hashmap containsKey() for the key it gave me, what type of key will cause the return value to be false?

Could you share the source code for Markup ?

For even more sanity, you may want to replace assert() with Kotlin's require() or check(). assert() depends on a JVM option which you need to remember to enable

@DavidSoroko true, but since the last assert fails, we know it's enabled.

Ah, good point.

"Waypoint doesn't provide overrides for hashCode() or equals()" - and presumably Markup doesn't either?

@k314159 correct.

Something is off. To simplify, a key (markup) that was known to be present in a map is not present in the same map a few lines latter. The map was not modified and presumably the markup data that contributes to its hashcode / equals was not modified either?

@DavidSoroko yes, I feel like I must be missing something. Java's hashmap is obviously completely battle tested. I can't get this to fail via unit tests that cover it many times over. I also can't get the hash key to work in production if I do override equals and hashcode for Waypoint. I haven't had an issue similar to this since I worked in c/c++.

Is the hashmap being modified by other threads?

Same question about the JsonObject member.

@DavidSoroko but JsonObject is immutable, so there shouldn't be any issue, theoretically.

It has been a while...and even it was, it should not affect the lookup using the same instance.

@DavidSoroko re JsonObject. Initially I was convinced that this shouldn't matter but if when adding the markup as a key the hash is calculated in the map and then if later before trying to look it up the members of the JO are modified in some way that could introduce a defect in using it this way? Need to test this. Could it explain why I'm unable to lookup the key when I just got the key from the hash - since the hash is cacluated on add, but the object at this time will return a new hash value. That must be it.

Well, if it is the same instance, it should not matter as equals/hashcode change on the instance and you have only references to it- one in your code and one in the map. In your example code, it is the same instance.

I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you please provide an executable example? Please also provide the import statements and example objects that lead to the error.

I can reproduce it. See my unit test above.

As the Javadoc for Map says: "great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys." In your case, the Markup class you use as a key is mutable, even though all its properties are val. It's "mutable" in the deep sense, because one of its properties is a JsonObject (presumably from Gson) which is itself mutable.
The equals and hashCode methods of data classes work recursively: Markup.equals calls geoJson.equals, and Markup.hashCode calls geoJson.hashCode. When you add a new property to geoJson, it now has a new hashcode, and therefore can't be found in the HashMap by direct lookup, although it can be found by filtering.
You can fix the issue by making Markup.uuid the key to your map, instead of the Markup object itself, assuming that every instance has a unique uuid. If that is not the case, then you will need to remove and reinsert the map entry every time you change its key.
